# Django: ordering numerical and string value with order_by

Tags: python, django, algorithm, sorting

My problem is, that obviously the data is ordered by UTF-8 codes since it's a Charfield, with the predictable results .. it sort the data like this;

My Data is:

```
1,8,7,2a, 4, 2, 11, 10...
```

I want this ordered list:

```
1,2,2a,4,7,8,10,11 ..
```

I really don't know how I can order this properly ..

Answer (score 1):

[natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) can do the magic. It's my all time favourite. Take them into list & apply natsort directly.

```
from natsort import natsorted
re = [1,2,'2a',4,7,8,10,11]
print(natsorted(re))
```

You get

```
[1, 2, '2a', 4, 7, 8, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split every element into two pairs, convert first pair to integer, then sort by the pairs:

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.11.3 (main, Apr  7 2023, 19:30:05) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.10.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: its = '1,8,7,2a, 4, 2, 11, 10'.replace(' ', '').split(',')

In [2]: its
Out[2]: ['1', '8', '7', '2a', '4', '2', '11', '10']

In [3]: import re

In [4]: def convert(s: str) -> tuple[int, str]:
   ...:     i = 0
   ...:     if m := re.match(r'\d+', s):
   ...:         j = m.group()
   ...:         i = int(j)
   ...:         s = s[len(j):]
   ...:     return (i, s)
   ...:

In [5]: [convert(i) for i in its]
Out[5]: [(1, ''), (8, ''), (7, ''), (2, 'a'), (4, ''), (2, ''), (11, ''), (10, '')]

In [6]: sorted(its, key=lambda x: convert(x))
Out[6]: ['1', '2', '2a', '4', '7', '8', '10', '11']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been given two pure Python solutions.  But your mention of Django suggests you want a solution that works inside of the database.

For that I would suggest storing two fields.  One is the original text.  The other is the text mangled so that it alphabetically sorts like you want.

For example you can take any string of digits, and then store it with leading 0s of fixed length.  So your list

```
1, 8, 7, 2a, 4, 2, 11, 10...
```

becomes

```
0000000000000001,
0000000000000008,
0000000000000007,
0000000000000002a,
0000000000000004,
0000000000000002,
0000000000000011,
0000000000000010,
```

Which sorts alphabetically as:

```
0000000000000001,
0000000000000002,
0000000000000002a,
0000000000000004,
0000000000000007,
0000000000000008,
0000000000000010,
0000000000000011,
```

And sorting on that field sorts your records with the original field sorted

```
1, 2, 2a, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11
```

But do think about how you want to do that.  The solution as I described it will turn

```
2, 2.5, 2.52, 3
```

into

```
0000000000000002,
0000000000000002.0000000000000005,
0000000000000002.0000000000000052,
0000000000000003,
```

which will sort as

```
2, 2.52, 2.5, 3
```

So add a rule for floats, and now you sort version numbers like this:

```
v1.1, v1.10, v1.11, v1.9
```

Only dive down this rabbit hole as far as you need for your use case.  But do be aware that it IS a rabbit hole.  And your answer can always be improved more.